# Highcharts bar zoom issue when using transparent series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I'm experiencing a strange **Highchart** **zoom** behavior when using **transparent** stuff.

Quite hard to explain, so I prepared [a quick video to show it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNw3IRlk2rI).

Have you experienced this kind of problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s50pjb8x/)

And the code:

```
$(function () {

    $('#roadmap-training').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            zoomType: 'y'
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: new Date(2014, 0, 1).getTime(),
            max: new Date(2014, 11, 31).getTime(),
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: "normal"
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            positioner: function () {
                return { x: 10, y: 35 };
            },
        },
        series: [
            {
                data: [
                    {
                        y: 864000000,
                    },
                    {
                        y: 12960000000,
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                data: [
                    {
                        y: new Date(2014, 1, 1).getTime(),
                        color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    {
                        y: new Date(2014, 8, 1).getTime(),
                        color: 'transparent'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Here is a real world example of graph I generate with this way of doing:
[image]

Comment: Good example. Is it possible to get your code in JSFiddle to try some solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason for using transparent series? Why not use column-range type? Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/yfz4usw5/

```
    series: [{
        data: [{
            high: new Date(2014, 1, 1).getTime() + 864000000,
            low: new Date(2014, 1, 1).getTime(),
        }, {
            high: new Date(2014, 8, 1).getTime() + 12960000000,
            low: new Date(2014, 8, 1).getTime(),
        }]
    }]
```

Sometimes issue indeed comes, but hard to guess what is the reason.

Comment: Hello Pawel, and thank you for your answer, looks promising !

I need to be able to put several bars on a same line, in order to generate a roadmap (~gantt) chart. Can you tell me how to achieve this using your technique?

Comment: Perfect Pawel, works like a charm! Thank you very much. The solution is embedded in a jQuery plugin: https://github.com/pascallando/highroadmap